# Running 2 cmd codes at runtime in java

Tags: java, cmd, compilation

I want to run 2 cmd commands consecutively. My purpose here, first compile file(with using cmd command not any other things like Java Compiler API), then run.

compiler.java:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class compiler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String dosCommand = "cmd /c java -cp ";
        final String classname = "example";
        final String location = "D:\\";




        try {
        final Process process2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /k javac D:\\example.java"); //I used /k to remain.
            final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(dosCommand + location + " " + classname);
            final InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
            final InputStream in2 = process.getErrorStream();
            int ch, ch2;
            while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) ch);
            }
            while ((ch2 = in2.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) ch2); // read error here
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

example.java:(in D:// path.)

```
  public class example { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      System.out.println("Hello, World");
   }
}
```

When I run compiler.java it gives

> Error: Couldn't find or load main class example

No problem in example.java. When I compile and run this example.java file in cmd it runs correctly.
My problem is to run 2 cmd commands consecutively. Finally, How can I run cmd commands consecutively?. Thanks...

Comment: Take a look at [`waitFor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()) method of `Process` to run two commands consecutively.